# Scala : Iterate through array and return the final result in the form of List with calculated values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, arraylist

I have a dataset and I am collecting the values to an form an array.

Sample Data:

```
val sampleData= Seq(
     ("1", "12"),
    ("2","22")
   ).toDF("id","value").as[(String,String)]
```

I have to iterate thru this dataset and form a resultant List(Map) with the values present in the dataset.

Output should look like

```
List(
    Map("id"-> "1", "value"->"12"),
    Map("id"-> "2", "value"->"22"))
```

I tried to create a variable `finalData` outside and tried to hold the value while iterating thru the array but this variable is not having any scope inside the `foreach` condition.

Snippet I tried

```
val finalData = List[Map[String,String]]
val someData = ReconResultDSDummy.collect().foreach(f => {
            var intermediateData = Map("id" -> f._1, "value" -> f._2)
            var finalData = finalData :+ intermediateData
    }
```

I am not able to recursively add values to `finalData` while iterating thru the data.

Please let me know what I am missing here or is there a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

A "basic" implementation would be to `map` each tuple to a `Map` rather than `foreach` which is for doing side effects but ignoring the result:

```scala
df
  .collect()
  .map(f => Map("id" -> f._1, "value" -> f._2))
// Gives a Seq[Map[String, String]]
```

One potentially important thing to note here is that calling `collect()` will load all data on the driver node in memory. If it does not fit in memory, it will fail.

Generally speaking, you'd want to do the `map()` before `collect()` to reduce what will be loaded on the driver. *In this specific case, I'm not sure it would make any real difference.*

Answer (score 2):

One important thing to understand about the Scala Collection API is that by default the collections are *immutable*. This means that the problem is not, as you think, that "this variable is not having any scope inside the `foreach` condition" but rather that what's happening inside the loop is that you are creating a new mutable reference with `var finalData`, binding it to the value of the immutable reference you created earlier with `val finalData` to which you append your `intermediateData`. The inner `finalData` *shadows* the inner `finalData`, although I have to say that the shadowing works in a very confusing way.

There are three possible ways of achieving what you want.

#### Use a mutable reference

```
val collected = ReconResultDSDummy.collect()
var finalData = List[Map[String, String]] // notice this is a `var`
collected.foreach(f => {
  val intermediateData = Map("id" -> f._1, "value" -> f._2)
  // Here you are appending `intermediateData` to the immutable `finalData`
  // and then re-assigning the newly created list to `finalData` itself
  finalData = finalData :+ intermediateData // note there's no `var` here
})
```

This is the least amount of change to your code and it works, but using a mutable reference to an immutable data structure is a bit clunky and possibly confusing to readers.

#### Use a mutable list

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Buffer
val collected = ReconResultDSDummy.collect()
val finalData = Buffer[Map[String, String]] // immutable reference to mutable data
collected.foreach(f => {
  val intermediateData = Map("id" -> f._1, "value" -> f._2)
  // here you are actually adding something to `finalData`
  finalData.addOne(intermediateData)
})
```

While this approach is seldom used in Scala, it's viable.

#### Process immutable data

```
val collected = ReconResultDSDummy.collect()
// `map` creates an entirely new collection, where each item in the new
// collection is the result of applying a function to each item in the old one 
val finalData = collected.map(f => {
  // no need to assign to anything here, this function is applied to each
  // item in `collected` and the result goes into `finalData`
  Map("id" -> f._1, "value" -> f._2)
})
```

This uses effectively the default immutable collections provided by Scala. This is also akin to how data is manipulated by Spark itself, so it's probably a very good fit for your code.

---

I wholeheartedly recommend you have a read at [the Scala documentation on collections](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections-2.13/introduction.html), as it goes much more in depth on this topic. Immutable collections are not the default in many widely available programming languages and require a bit of learning to be understood.

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the data before `collect` and apply a simple `map`,

using foldLeft it would be as shown below

```
 val sampleData = Seq(
    ("1", "12"),
    ("2", "22")
  ).toDF("id", "value").as[(String, String)]

 val outputMap = sampleData.collect()
   .foldLeft[List[Map[String,String]]](List.empty)
    { (accumulator, newRow) =>
      accumulator :+ Map("id" -> newRow._1,"value" -> newRow._2)
    }
 println(s"Map :$outputMap")
 /*
    Map :List(Map(id -> 1, value -> 12), Map(id -> 2, value -> 22))
 */
```